# How to call native CLR methods in .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, clr, pinvoke, .net-4.8

I am attempting to patch the fact that `ConditionalWeakTable<TKey, TValue>` doesn't have enumerator support on .NET Framework. I have hunted high and low for an alternative, but being that internally it calls `DependentHandle` which calls directly into the GC there doesn't seem to be a better solution I can hack together without unintended memory leaks.

But in the Source code for DependentHandle it uses several calls methods marked with `[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]` and from what I understand those are calling into the CLR directly.

```cs
[System.Security.SecurityCritical]
[ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.AppDomain)]
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
private static extern void nInitialize(Object primary, Object secondary, out IntPtr dependentHandle);
```

### Full Code of DependentHandle

```cs
    struct DependentHandle
    {
        #region Constructors
#if FEATURE_CORECLR
        [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical] // auto-generated
#else
        [System.Security.SecurityCritical]
#endif
        public DependentHandle(Object primary, Object secondary)
        {
            IntPtr handle = (IntPtr)0;
            nInitialize(primary, secondary, out handle);
            // no need to check for null result: nInitialize expected to throw OOM.
            _handle = handle;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Members
        public bool IsAllocated
        {
            get
            {
                return _handle != (IntPtr)0;
            }
        }

        // Getting the secondary object is more expensive than getting the first so
        // we provide a separate primary-only accessor for those times we only want the
        // primary.
#if FEATURE_CORECLR
        [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical] // auto-generated
#else
        [System.Security.SecurityCritical]
#endif
        public Object GetPrimary()
        {
            Object primary;
            nGetPrimary(_handle, out primary);
            return primary;
        }

#if FEATURE_CORECLR
        [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical] // auto-generated
#else
        [System.Security.SecurityCritical]
#endif
        public void GetPrimaryAndSecondary(out Object primary, out Object secondary)
        {
            nGetPrimaryAndSecondary(_handle, out primary, out secondary);
        }

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Forces dependentHandle back to non-allocated state (if not already there)
        // and frees the handle if needed.
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [System.Security.SecurityCritical]
        public void Free()
        {
            if (_handle != (IntPtr)0)
            {
                IntPtr handle = _handle;
                _handle = (IntPtr)0;
                nFree(handle);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Members
        [System.Security.SecurityCritical]
        [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.AppDomain)]
        [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
        private static extern void nInitialize(Object primary, Object secondary, out IntPtr dependentHandle);

        [System.Security.SecurityCritical]
        [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
        [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
        private static extern void nGetPrimary(IntPtr dependentHandle, out Object primary);

        [System.Security.SecurityCritical]
        [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
        [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
        private static extern void nGetPrimaryAndSecondary(IntPtr dependentHandle, out Object primary, out Object secondary);

        [System.Security.SecurityCritical]
        [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
        [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
        private static extern void nFree(IntPtr dependentHandle);
        #endregion

        #region Private Data Member
        private IntPtr _handle;
        #endregion

    }
```

In theory, since my application is already running on .NET Framework and those internal calls actually should exist, it seems like I should be able to call them. But when instantiating an instance of `DependentHandle`, it throws:

```
System.Security.SecurityException
  HResult=0x8013150A
  Message=ECall methods must be packaged into a system module.
  Source=ConsoleApp45
  StackTrace:
   at ConsoleApp45.DependentHandle.nInitialize(Object primary, Object secondary, IntPtr& dependentHandle)
   at ConsoleApp45.DependentHandle..ctor(Object primary, Object secondary) in C:\Users\shad\source\repos\ConsoleApp45\ConsoleApp45\Program.cs:line 98
   at ConsoleApp45.ConditionalWeakTable`2.Container.CreateEntryNoResize(TKey key, TValue value) in C:\Users\shad\source\repos\ConsoleApp45\ConsoleApp45\Program.cs:line 671
   at ConsoleApp45.ConditionalWeakTable`2.CreateEntry(TKey key, TValue value) in C:\Users\shad\source\repos\ConsoleApp45\ConsoleApp45\Program.cs:line 561
   at ConsoleApp45.ConditionalWeakTable`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value) in C:\Users\shad\source\repos\ConsoleApp45\ConsoleApp45\Program.cs:line 263
   at ConsoleApp45.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\shad\source\repos\ConsoleApp45\ConsoleApp45\Program.cs:line 23
```

I tried searching for an answer to this, but I am not even sure how to phrase the question. I see that Microsoft [recently made `DependentHandle` public on .NET 6](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/54246/files/c9c632552ccfb9c9322435735bbe8a029321d27e#diff-c0c590b7df328eb409cac250d67defb2f6bed6a5243d92abbc5e0dc36661fd3e), but while that tells me what some of the C++ code looks like and hints at where to look for it in .NET Framework it is not much help beyond that.

From here, I suspect I need to find the native code that it is trying to execute and change my attributes to call it. So, I tried using:

- `[DllImport("clr.dll")]`
- `[DllImport("mscorlib.dll")]`

But in both cases I got a similar exception:

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80131523
  Message=Unable to find an entry point named 'nInitialize' in DLL 'mscorlib.dll'.
  Source=ConsoleApp45
  StackTrace:
   at ConsoleApp45.DependentHandle.nInitialize(Object primary, Object secondary, IntPtr& dependentHandle)
   at ConsoleApp45.DependentHandle..ctor(Object primary, Object secondary) in C:\Users\shad\source\repos\ConsoleApp45\ConsoleApp45\Program.cs:line 108
   at ConsoleApp45.ConditionalWeakTable`2.Container.CreateEntryNoResize(TKey key, TValue value) in C:\Users\shad\source\repos\ConsoleApp45\ConsoleApp45\Program.cs:line 683
   at ConsoleApp45.ConditionalWeakTable`2.CreateEntry(TKey key, TValue value) in C:\Users\shad\source\repos\ConsoleApp45\ConsoleApp45\Program.cs:line 573
   at ConsoleApp45.ConditionalWeakTable`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value) in C:\Users\shad\source\repos\ConsoleApp45\ConsoleApp45\Program.cs:line 275
   at ConsoleApp45.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\shad\source\repos\ConsoleApp45\ConsoleApp45\Program.cs:line 33
```

The above exception happened whether or not I had the `[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]` attribute on `nInitialize`.

At this point I am not sure whether I am looking in the wrong DLL, I am doing something wrong, or whether this is even possible to do. All of the questions I can find on P/Invoke involve a C/C++ library that the developer is supplying, not part of the CLR itself. Is it possible to call a **built-in CLR native method** from C#, and if so, how?

> **NOTE:** I only need this for .NET Framework 4.5+.

> **Update 2022-09-20 (Workaround):** Rather than back-porting `ConditionalWeakTable<TKey, TValue>` to .NET Framework and .NET Standard 2.0, we ended up using [weak events](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/pull/613) for each element of the collection to return a reference to itself so the references can be "iterated". We don't really care about order, so this was good enough to meet our needs.

Comment: You are locked out, your are seemingly fighting against the security architecture of the runtime. You might have to resort to injecting the runtime from unmanaged code at the kernel level. However, i would take this to github to get an authoritative answer. There might be some sacrificial dark magic that is available to you, though because this is framework and the world has moved on, this also might be a loosing battle

Comment: @TheGeneral - Thanks. I guess I will take it up with them. Sadly, there doesn't seem to be a technical reason why the enumerator doesn't exist. They added 2 more native calls in .NET Core 2.0, but they are not required for the enumerator support. And this is literally the only API we have a limitation with in .NET Framework in a 500K line application. We support .NET Core 3.1/.NET 5/.NET 6 as well, but it sucks having a leaky workaround for .NET Framework just because we need the enumerator of `ConditionalWeakTable`.